# How to read an HTML table with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to read the table with the cities from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_Switzerland)

Essential I want all the cities names but I am stuck at the part where i traverse to the inside of the table.

Select code.

```
 Element table = rawCities.getElementById("content")
                 .getElementById("bodyContent")
                 .getElementById("mw-content-text")
                 .select("table.wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter").first()
                 `.select("tbody").first()`;
```

So the document is downloaded and parsed with Jsoup.connect in another class and here I am trying to get the city names. When I traverse with selects I get a NullPointerException here. If I get rid of the `.select("tbody").first()`
the program runs but debugger shows table variable null. Should I be doing this in an other way or did I get something wrong?

Comment: What is the purpose of `jquery-tablesorter`? Also to `select` many classes of some element use `element.class1.class2` so your `table.wikitable sortable` should probably be `table.wikitable.sortable`.

Comment: Oh didn't know this.That solved the problem! Thank you very much. I though that `jquery-tablesorter` was part of the class name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print `rawCities` you will most probably not find any element which would represent tag `<jquery-tablesorter>`. So you should remove it from your `select`.

Another problem is that `table.wikitable sortable` will try to find

```
<table class="wikitable">
  ...
    <sortable>
  ...
</table>
```

***not***

```
<table class"wikitable sortable">...
```

To find element with few classes use `.` operator before each class name like `element.class1.class2` not *space* (which describes ancestor-child relationship) `element.class1 class2`.

So your code could be simplified to

```
Element table = rawCities
        .select("table.wikitable.sortable tbody")
        .first();
```

---

Anyway if you only want to print content of first column of selected table you can do it with

```
for (Element row : rawCities.select("table.wikitable.sortable td:eq(0) a")) {
    System.out.println(row.text());
}
```

You can use this loop to also add results of `row.text()` to some `List<String>` created earlier or use code like

```
List<String> names = rawCities
        .select("table.wikitable.sortable td:eq(0) a")
        .stream()
        .map(e -> e.text())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Then I don't need the `.getElementById("content")
                 .getElementById("bodyContent")
                 .getElementById("mw-content-text")` to reach the table?

Comment: No, `select` will try to find result which matches CSS query even if it is not directly on top level of ancestor/parent element. It could find any child/descendent.

Comment: I suspect that you may also not need `first`. If you want to simply iterate over all rows of table you can use something like `for (Element row : rawCities.select("table.wikitable.sortable tr")){...}`. If you want to find first `td` in its `tr` parent you can add `td:eq(0)`. More info at http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: Yes I want to add all of the city names in an arraylist. I will try this and see. Thanks for the tip

Comment: No they will be used many times. It is about an desktop app for optimal transportation routes and no I have never used streams. Can they somehow improve the code here? If so I will be off to read

Comment: I updated my answer a little. Try and see if that is the thing you want to achieve. I am trying to select links `<a...>` inside `td` to avoid this `1` added after names.

Comment: That is exactly what I wrote myself. I will try to stay away from streams though because I want the code to be Java 7 compatible. Thanks for the help.